# How to resolve : Diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, frameworks, cocoapods

while execute the application i got the following error.

platform :ios, '7.0'

target 'DemoApp' do

pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'

pod 'GoogleMaps'

pod 'GooglePlacePicker'

pod 'Crashlytics'

end

target 'SampleAppTests' do

end

[image]

Comment: run the pod install and then open the workspace file

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the error. Run `pod install` in Terminal to install the Pods. This will generate a new **workspace** which you should open and work on your project.

So, `$ cd` to the folder of your project and then run `pod install`.

Comment: @user3829315 did the pod install command created new workspace for you? In my case the problem is not solved by issuing this command and neither the workspace was created/updated. Can you give more information   on how you fixed the problem?